# When is the 'remaining > wait' conditional statement ever true in underscore.js's implementation of throttle?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, throttling

Library code (line 860 in question):
https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js

`if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait)`

When is the second half of this true?

Background - first post on SO and pretty new to javascript coding.  I've reimplemented throttle from scratch as an exercise and I'm comparing my version to the library function.  I don't understand why this part of the conditional statement exists in the library function because it appears to me that it will never be true, so I think I'm missing something.  Can someone fill me in by providing a situation where the referenced statement is true?

I've run it through a debugger and googled for articles but haven't found an answer.

Full library function:

```
_.throttle = function(func, wait, options) {
    var timeout, context, args, result;
    var previous = 0;
    if (!options) options = {};

    var later = function() {
      previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : _.now();
      timeout = null;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    };

    var throttled = function() {
      var now = _.now();
      if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
      var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
      context = this;
      args = arguments;
      if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) { // THIS LINE
        if (timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = null;
        }
        previous = now;
        result = func.apply(context, args);
        if (!timeout) context = args = null;
      } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
        timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
      }
      return result;
    };

    throttled.cancel = function() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      previous = 0;
      timeout = context = args = null;
    };

    return throttled;
  };
```

I can't picture 'remaining' ever being greater than 'wait.'  When would this happen?

Comment: My guess is it's just the lodash people covering their butts - likely out of habit

Comment: This could happen if `previous` is greater than `now`. I don't know when this might happen, but `options.trailing` and `options.leading` look like they could modify their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition handles the case when the system time was being changed while `throttle` is in fly.

It may seem like a super edge case but actually there are a lot of reasons time may change. You can change your system time manually or it may be changed automatically (e.g. because of synchronization with [ntp server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)), you can travel and your timezone is changed and of course, don't forget about [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

I've made a [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dll8zc) where you can investigate it deeper.

This condition was introduced in this commit: [Allow _.throttle to function correctly after the system time is updated](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/7479a2415e738194046fbee55582bc9570d8b458#diff-0f36b362a0b81d6f4d4bfd8a7413c75d).

P.S. I faced time-related issues on almost each of my projects and I am very grateful to all these people who think about such things.